# The signature info is not being displayed correctly, when the pdf is digitally signed by a Pseudonym Certificate

Tags: pdf, certificate, itext, digital-signature, acrobat

**Background:**

- I have written a java program using itext library to sign PDF with ikey.
- I have two ikeys, one with a Common Name certificate, and the other has a Pseudonym certificate.

**Description:**

When I open the pdf signed by the **Common Name** cert in Acrobat Reader, it displays the blue ribbon meaning it's a valid signature, and in the Signature Panel it shows "**Certified by Jane Doe**". Everything is perfect.

However, if the certificate is a **Pseudonym certificate**, it displayed "**Certified by %s**". 
In spite of the blue ribbon and the validation info all display correctly.(Not allowed to attach image, so put Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/366Vf.jpg)

**Questions:**

1. Is this an issue with the Acrobat Reader, that it cannot display correct "Certified by" info if the pdf is signed by a Pseudonym certificate?
2. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: @mkl Many thanks for looking at this issue.I've sent it to your email

Comment: I took a look at your file and could not find anything wrong in its signature; neither could I find a hint in ISO 32000-1 indicating that pseudonym certificates might be forbidden here. I assume, therefore, that Adobe Reader signature status display code simply forgot to consider the possibility of pseudonym signatures (most likely because Adobe generally has use cases targeted at specific persons, not roles or functions, in mind). Probably Leonard (the person Bruno most likely asked) knows more. You might want to try using the **Name** entry of the signature dictionary. I haven't checked this

Answer (score 0):

I have seen **Certified by %s** before. See [my book about digital signatures](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) figure 2.23. I quote:

> As expected, Alice’s certification signature is invalid after Carol
>   tried to sign the document using a  second certification signature,
>   but the output is kind of strange. In the signature panel, we see
>   ‘Certified by %s’ instead of ‘Certified by Carol’, and there’s a
>   looking glass instead of a red cross. These situations are rather
>   exotic and should be avoided. Let’s focus on real life examples, and 
>   combine signing with form filling.

This quote is about the results of some experiments that conflict with the ISO specification / PAdES. You may have found another conflict.

In my book, I describe a situation where there are two certification signatures. This doesn't make sense as it is explicitly forbidden to add two certification signatures. It is also implied in the specs that the certification signature is *always the first* signature, although Adobe Reader doesn't complain (yet) if it isn't.

I can easily imagine that using a pseudonym certificate is also one of those exotic cases where Adobe Reader doesn't really know what to do. What is the sense of signing a document anonymously? Who should Adobe Reader pick as the authorized signer?

The fact that I've seen **%s** before, tells me (without even looking at your PDF) that **%s** is an artifact from Adobe Reader. I wrote some of the signing functionality in iText and I'm sure that we don't put the **%s** there.

Comment: *What is the sense of signing a document anonymously? Who should Adobe Reader pick as the authorized signer?* - Not anonymously, there is a pseudonym which may indeed be well known to the parties involved.

Comment: I'm very interested to hear if it can be reproduced with *all* Pseudonym Certificates or just the one mentioned by the OP. I'll ask somebody at Adobe.

Comment: Glad to have the opportunity to say thank you @BrunoLowagie Your book has helped me a lot. In this particular case, I've test with two Pseudonym Certificates, both issued by Quovadis, and the behavior are the same. It seems to me that, the Adobe Reader likes the validation of the signature, but just doesn't know how to handle Pseudonym Certificate when it come to displaying that field.

Comment: Well, your question was sent to the PDF architect at Adobe. When you get an answer will depend on whether or not he's traveling for the moment (he's evangelizing PDF all over the world). Usually he routes the questions I send him to the engineer responsible for the area specific to the question. I don't remember a question to which he didn't respond.